# running laravel queue listen when exiting terminal

Tags: laravel-5

I have setup job in laravel thats time consuming so user get upload file and exit, and it works just fine when I do php artisan queue:listen or queue:work.

But that doesn't work when I get out of terminal. What do I need to do to have it work automatically?

I've tried amazon aws sqs, but that's useless because I can queue the job but thats about it, it doesn't have option to set endpoint to hit on job received.

I know there is iron.io but that outside of my budget.

Below is my code to push the job to database

```
public function queue()
   {
       $user = Property::find(1);
       $this->dispatch(new SendReportEmail($user));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say Amazon sqs is useless
you can use a job on your [scheduled jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) in laravel and use taht to recieve jobs from amazon sqs which has reference to the file / row to be processed and you can get the payload for the job and accordingly process that with the scheduled job.

For help here is a [tutorial on setting up a queue listener for sqs via laravel](http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2014-help-with-setting-up-a-queue-listener)

Comment: Could you give me psudo code ? I haven't used laravel scheduled jobs yet